# How could I compare lists in lists?

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter

I have two lists:

```
a = [[7, 2, -1, -6, -100], [-1, 0, 5, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
b = [[1],[2],[0,0,1,0,0]]
```

I use:

```
result = filter(lambda x: x not in b, a)
```

My expected result should be:

```
[[7, 2, -1, -6, -100], [-1, 0, 5, 2, 3]]
```

Why I get:

```
[[7, 2, -1, -6, -100], [-1, 0, 5, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

I hope someone could help me with this! Thx:)

Comment: i get your expected result, i don't see anything wrong with above code

Comment: your code is working just fine. ```list(filter(lambda x: x not in b, a))```

Answer (score 0):

Your code work as expected, you may print the wrong variable.

```py
a = [[7, 2, -1, -6, -100], [-1, 0, 5, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
b = [[1],[2],[0,0,1,0,0]]
result = list(filter(lambda x: x not in b, a))
print(result)
```

You get

```py
[[7, 2, -1, -6, -100], [-1, 0, 5, 2, 3]]
```

Howerver, if you thing that filter, will filter inplace and modify you varibale a, its a mistake.

```py
print(a)
```

You get

```py
[[7, 2, -1, -6, -100], [-1, 0, 5, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

## Note

In python 3, filter return a generator you need to exhaust it in order to get the desired output, one way to it is :

```py
list(filter(...))
```